# EVPN MAC Advertisement route not installed to L2 forwarding table

Tags: juniper, evpn

I have a [VLAN-based EVPN](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/example/evpn-based-services.html) connecting two sites in a lab environment based on the network topology described in the [DAY ONE: USING ETHERNET VPNS FOR DATA CENTER INTERCONNECT](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/jnbooks/en_US/day-one-books/) book:

[image: EVPN test setup]

For some reason, it looks like the MAC Advertisement routes from remote PEs are not installed to `mac-table` of the local PE. For example, there is a route for MAC address `fe:86:dd:0e:ff:f3` in `EVPN-1.evpn.0` table:

```
2:11.11.11.11:1::100::fe:86:dd:0e:ff:f3/304 MAC/IP (1 entry, 1 announced)
        *BGP    Preference: 170/-101
                Route Distinguisher: 11.11.11.11:1
                Next hop type: Indirect, Next hop index: 0
                Address: 0xcf04ff0
                Next-hop reference count: 35
                Source: 1.1.1.1
                Protocol next hop: 11.11.11.11
                Indirect next hop: 0x2 no-forward INH Session ID: 0x0
                State: <Secondary Active Int Ext>
                Local AS: 65000 Peer AS: 65000
                Age: 15:11:12   Metric2: 2
                Validation State: unverified
                Task: BGP_65000.1.1.1.1+179
                Announcement bits (1): 0-EVPN-1-evpn
                AS path: I  (Originator)
                Cluster list:  1.1.1.1
                Originator ID: 11.11.11.11
                Communities: target:65000:1
                Import Accepted
                Route Label: 299888
                ESI: 00:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11
                Localpref: 100
                Router ID: 1.1.1.1
                Primary Routing Table bgp.evpn.0
                Indirect next hops: 1
                        Protocol next hop: 11.11.11.11 Metric: 2
                        Indirect next hop: 0x2 no-forward INH Session ID: 0x0
                        Indirect path forwarding next hops: 1
                                Next hop type: Router
                                Next hop: 10.21.1.1 via ge-0/0/5.0
                                Session Id: 0x0
                                11.11.11.11/32 Originating RIB: inet.3
                                  Metric: 2     Node path count: 1
                                  Forwarding nexthops: 1
                                        Nexthop: 10.21.1.1 via ge-0/0/5.0
                                        Session Id: 0
```

I would expect to see the MAC address of `fe:86:dd:0e:ff:f3` in the local PE `mac-table` with a flag `R`(Remote PE MAC) set, but it is not there:

```
root@PE21> show evpn mac-table

MAC flags       (S -static MAC, D -dynamic MAC, L -locally learned, C -Control MAC
    O -OVSDB MAC, SE -Statistics enabled, NM -Non configured MAC, R -Remote PE MAC, P -Pinned MAC)

Routing instance : EVPN-1
 Bridging domain : __EVPN-1__, VLAN : 100
   MAC                 MAC      Logical          NH     MAC         active
   address             flags    interface        Index  property    source
   fe:96:dd:0e:ff:f4   D        ae0.100

root@PE21>
```

EVPN configuration on local PE(`PE21`) and remote PE(`PE11`) can be seen below:

```
root@PE21> show configuration routing-instances EVPN-1
instance-type evpn;
vlan-id 100;
interface ae0.100;
routing-interface irb.100;
route-distinguisher 21.21.21.21:1;
vrf-target target:65000:1;
protocols {
    evpn {
        default-gateway do-not-advertise;
    }
}

root@PE21>


root@PE11> show configuration routing-instances EVPN-1
instance-type evpn;
vlan-id 100;
interface ae0.100;
routing-interface irb.100;
route-distinguisher 11.11.11.11:1;
vrf-target target:65000:1;
protocols {
    evpn {
        default-gateway do-not-advertise;
    }
}

root@PE11>
```

Local CE port configuration is following:

```
root@CE20> show configuration interfaces ae0
aggregated-ether-options {
    lacp {
        active;
        periodic fast;
    }
}
unit 0 {
    family bridge {
        interface-mode trunk;
        vlan-id-list [ 100 200 201 202 222 ];
    }
}

root@CE20>
```

What might cause such behavior?

Comment: What router models do you have?

Comment: Can you post configs for the remote PE's routing instance as well as the CE interface (assuming they're the same?).

Comment: Router model is Juniper vMX. I updated my question with the remote PE RI config.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.